# Quitar seleccion del primer elemento de un Qtablewidget PyQt5 con Phyton

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Estoy trabajando en PyQt5 y Python.
He utilizado un QtWidget y funciona bien todo pero cuando se dibuja y rellena siempre aparece seleccionado el primer elemento de la primera fila incluso sin que se haya dado click sobre éste (se resalta el rectángulo de la celda correspondiente al primer elemento).
He probado varias formas de rellenar el QtWidget y siempre sucede igual, es como si por defecto el foco del widget apareciera siempre en el primer elemento y cuando trato de evaluar mediante un botón en el formulario si hay algo seleccionado me da como resultado éste elemento. O sea, que aunque el usuario no haya seleccionado nada siempre está seleccionado el primero. Cuando el usuario selecciona se pinta de azul.
¿Que deseo? Que cuando el usuario no seleccione nada en el QTable y yo tome la lectura de este widget el valor de self.proy me de como resultado que está vacío y no el valor de la primera celda.

*Carga el QWidget que fue creado en PyQt5*

```
   def cargar_tw(self):

    valores = self.Mtos.query('SELECT cod_proy, nomb_proy FROM Proyecto')
   
    for lineIndex, lineData in enumerate(valores):
        if lineIndex == 0:
            self.tw.setColumnCount(len(valores[0]))
            self.tw.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Referencia','Nombre del Proyecto'))
            #(len(lineData))
        self.tw.insertRow(lineIndex)
        for columnIndex, columnData in enumerate(lineData):
            self.tw.setItem(lineIndex, columnIndex, QTableWidgetItem(str(columnData)))
```

*Valida que se seleccione un valor de proyecto*

```
def valida_proy(self):
   row = self.tw.currentRow()
   item = self.tw.item(row, 0)
   if item == "":
       return False
   else:
       self.proy = item.text()
       print(self.proy)
       return True, self.proy
```

*Valida que se seleccione un valor de donante*

```
def valida_don(self):
   self.don = self.cb_cod_don_fp.currentText()
   if self.don == "":
       return False
   else:
       return True, self.don

def actualizar_proy(self):
   
   if not self.valida_don() or not self.valida_proy():
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Informacion", "Debe elegir un Proyecto y un Donante para Financiar")
   
   else:
       res_cons_sel = self.Mtos.consulta_de_seleccion_multiple('cod_proy_fp,cod_don_fp', 'FinanciarProy', 'cod_proy_fp', 'cod_don_fp', (self.proy,self.don))
```

*res_cons_sel devuelve una lista. Hace una llamada a otro modulo y no tiene problemas en su ejecución*

```
       if res_cons_sel:
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Informacion", "El proyecto y donante seleccionados ya se encuentran registrados")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Me suena a problema xy. Por que necesitas que no haya selección?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y me disculpo por mi ignorancia. No he agregado el codigo porque este problema sale cada vez que se rellena el QWidget a traves de cualquier metodo por lo que lo veo de manera general con independencia de como se rellene el widget. Si es necesario reformulo la pregunta...

Comment: En mi caso particular me gustaria saber que no hay nada seleccionado para validar que el usuario no intente dejarlo en blanco porque el dato que debe entrar es obligatorio para posteriormente ejecutar una consulta sqlite que valida que el dato no se repita en una table, sin embargo de entrada ya selecciona el primer elemento.

Comment: He reeditado la pregunta, espero sea de utilidad, gracias...

Comment: No te es conveniente, en lugar de validar si hay o no algo seleccionado, que el usuario no pueda desseleccionar un item y aparesca uno seleccionado por default?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que, de seleccionar un item en el combo y no seleccionar nada en el qtable, se alerte al usuario de que tiene que seleccionar algo en el qtable. Después de comprobar que la combinacion no existe se agrega a la tabla sqlite (no he puesto el código). Lo que no entiendo es la razón por la cual se ubica el cursor en la primera celda cada vez que se carga el qtable y he probado de varias formas a rellenarlo, al posicionarse en la primera celda este valor me es siempre devuelto si realizar ninguna seleccion.

Answer (score 1):

He hallado la solución, al menos funciona para mí.
En lugar de evaluar si la primera celda está seleccionada, he evaluado si el usuario ha seleccionado una fila. Si a alguien puede servir les pongo la variante en la función. Agradezco mucho sus respuestas.

*Valida que se seleccione un valor de proyecto*

```
def on_select_tw(self):
   filaSeleccionada = self.tw.selectedItems()
   if not filaSeleccionada:
    return False
   else:
    row = self.tw.currentRow()
    item = self.tw.item(row, 0)
    self.proy = item.text()
    return True, self.proy
```